# openssl_private_decrypt() "RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error"

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

#### Problem Statement

I'm trying to decrypt data using private_key from PKCS12 formatted file by [openssl_private_decrypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php). However I'm getting empty string in response.

---

#### Exception

```
[
    0 => "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"
    1 => "error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error"
    2 => "error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed"
]
```

---

#### Files & Configuration

```
$pkcs12 = file_get_contents('/path/server.p12');

openssl_pkcs12_read($pkcs12, $p12, '123456');

if (false === openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $p12['pkey'], OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING))
{

    $e = [];
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
        array_push($e, $msg);

    dd($e);

}
```

---

#### Edit 1:

1. I've run the following command to generate CSR as well as private key for SSL certificates

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.csr
```

- example.key (Private key in `.key` format)
- example.csr (CSR)

2. Got certificate & files from CA.

- example.crt
- intermediate.crt
- example.pem

3. Run below command to convert private key and certificate into to PKCS12 file.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in example.crt -inkey example.key -out example.p12 -certfile intermediate.crt
```

- example.p12

---

#### Edit 2:

I've `example.key` header

```
"""
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n
aasdasdddddddddddddadsssssssjhjjjjjjjjjj\n
.
.
asddddddddasdkjabshjdhajskdhajgggggggggg\n
TtasdhjaskjZPqD0UcJAcP\n
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
"""
```

---

#### Edit 3:

I've converted private key from `.key` to `.pem` using below command but still getting same error.

```
openssl rsa -in example.key -text > example.key.pem
```

---

#### Edit 4:

After some research I found out that `'\n'` could be the cause of this error as stated in [@derN3rd](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/642#issuecomment-585173594).

**1. Declaring local variable**

```
$pkcs8pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
.
.
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

dd($pkcs8pem);
```

Output:

```
"""
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n
.
.
ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ\n
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
"""
```

**2. Using str_replace()**

```
$privateKey = $p12['pkey'];
$privateKeyClean = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $privateKey);
dd($privateKeyClean);
```

Output:

```
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

---

Comment: The code works on my machine when using my own .p12 file and ciphertext generated with it. The first error message indicates that `$p12['pkey']` does not contain a valid PEM private key. The `$p12` read, specifically `$p12['pkey']`, should look like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-openssl_pkcs12_read-function/). The other two errors may be sequential errors, but may also indicate a problem with the ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco, Can I directly use private key  in `.pem`. Can you help me to convert privateKey from `.key` to `.pem` format.

Comment: Typically, the PKCS#8 format or the PKCS#1 format is used for private RSA keys, either DER or PEM encoded. A PEM encoded PKCS#8 key has the header _BEGIN PRIVATE KEY_, a PEM encoded PKCS#1 key _BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY_. The DER encoded key results when the body of a PEM key is Base64 decoded. It is not clear to me which format is contained in _.key_. You would have to determine this format or post a **test** key.

Comment: @Topaco, I've added privatekey header in question. Please revisit the question

Comment: @Topaco, Is it because there is "\n" in my string of privateKey.

Comment: Quite possible. Format the key analogous to the example I posted on paiza: Line breaks so that header and footer are on separate lines. In the body there is a line break after every 64 characters.

Comment: @Topaco, Please revisit the question. I tried with removing '\n' and declaring variable. But still getting same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233317/discussion-between-topaco-and-maqsud).